# Powershell Get-ADUser split filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is it possible to modify a ADProperty within a filter?
The use I want it for is to be able to check if there already is a user with a certain name in a specific OU.
Something like this:

```
$ou="HQOffice"
Get-ADUser -Properties Displayname -Filter {Displayname -eq "Major Minor" -and (DistinguishedName).split(',')[2].split('=')[1] -eq $ou}
```

Comment: No, use the `-SearchBase` parameter to specify an OU and set the `-SearchScope` parameter to `OneLevel` if you want only immediate child objects in that OU